# How to separate each index from dataframe with duplicate indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
   y
0, 0.3234
0, 0.5234
1, 0.3234
1, 0.7854
1, 0.1863
2, 0.0021
```

As you can see there are dplicate indices. when I access by index, it returns all the values with that index. So I decided to split them on the basis of indices like y1 with first value with 0 index, first value with 1 index, first value with 2 index etc. Similarly y2 with second value with 0 index, second value with 1 index, second value with 2 index etc. As the number of times an index appears is not constant, I want the new dataframes y1, y2, y3, y4 etc till the max(number oftimes index occurs for index in y.index) and fill out the remaining values with NaNs.
Like the separated datafraames look like:

y1:

```
   y1
0, 0.3234
1, 0.3234
2, 0.0021
```

y2:

```
   y2
0, 0.5234
1, 0.7854
```

y3:

```
   y3
1, 0.1863
```

I have tried accessing with index and alist comprehension with [i[0] for i in y.iterrows()] but it does not work either. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need `cumcount` + string concatenation and a `groupby`. we can return the results to a dict of dataframes.

```
dfs = { k : v.drop('key',1) for k,v in 
   df.assign(key='y' + 
               (df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1).astype(str))\
               .groupby('key')}

print(dfs['y1'])

        y
0  0.3234
1  0.3234
2  0.0021

print(dfs['y2'])

        y
0  0.5234
1  0.7854


print(dfs['y3'])
        y
1  0.1863
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but @Datanovice how would I create new dataframes with each of these indices. I can create from reset_index() but it would not retain information that which value belongs to which index?

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice! This is exactly what I needed. Never knew that so far fetched functions like `groupby()` and `cumcount()` could be used in such a beautiful way together

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
df['z']=df.groupby(df.index).cumcount()
y=df[df.z==0]#Select group index 0
y1=df[df.z==1]#Select group index 1
y2=df[df.z==2]#Select group index 2

  print(y.iloc[:,:1:])#Slice out z column used to sort
         y
0,  0.3234
1,  0.3234
2,  0.0021



print(y1.iloc[:,:1:])#Slice out z column used to sort
         y
0,  0.5234
1,  0.7854

print(y2.iloc[:,:1:])#Slice out z column used to sort
      y
1,  0.1863
```

Comment: Hey @wwnde! Thanks for the help but I think this is pretty much the same way as @Datanovice suggested except that here we are doing explicitly. Moreover I think it would not scale if I have (which I have) more distinct indices or frequencies of indices

Comment: Appreciate your comment. Many ways to get to the same. Hadn't read @Datanovice answer. Will leave mine here just in case someone else benefits in future. Thats what the platform is for (:-Thanks though